How can I integrate values of a color channel with the image dimensions using cv2?
Using cv2, one can load an image into Python and directly transfer the image into a grayscale version, as shown below.
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("/path-to-image", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

Then, the image is a two dimensional numpy array. Hence, the intensity of the gray colors for each pixel are integrated into the height and width dimensions of the image.
image.shape
(720, 1024)

As we can see above, the image or numpy array has only two dimensions, height (720) and width (1024). Each value or pixel in this matrix consists of a specific value, where the value corresponds to the brightness or gray color of the respective pixel.
Selecting single color channels:
Now, I am interested in the three color channels of the image, that is, in the red, green, and blue channels. It is possible to pick the three color channels as follows when we don't load the image in a grayscaled format.
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("/path-to-image", 1) # the value 1 means to load the original color image
for color in ["red", "green", "blue"]:
            if color == "red":
                red[:,:,0] = 0
                red[:,:,1] = 0
            elif color == "green":
                green[:,:,0] = 0
                green[:,:,2] = 0
            elif color == "blue":
                blue[:,:,1] = 0
                blue[:,:,2] = 0

Paradigmatically, plotting the red image then works as follows:
cv2.imshow("red image plot", red)
cv2.waitKey(0)

So far so good.
My problem and question:
I would like to integrate the color values for each pixel into a two dimensional numpy array, exactly as it is automatically done when I directly load the image as grayscale format via image = cv2.imread("/path-to-image", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).
When I individually select the color channels I get a three dimensional numpy array, respectively for each color channel. Here is an example for the red color channel:
red.shape
(720, 1024, 3)

How can I now "integrate" the color channel values, such as in the case of the red image, from the three dimensional into a two dimensional numpy array, as automatically performed when I load the image as grayscale?
Therefore, my aim is to get a two dimensional numpy array or matrix, where each pixel in that matrix is the color value for the red color.

"the intensity of the gray colors for each pixel are integrated into the height and width dimensions of the image" -- huh?

If you want to extract a single colour channel from a multichannel (e.g. BGR) image, it's rather trivial -- in fact you already did it 6 times in your question: image[:,:,2] gets you a view of the third channel (in case of BGR that would be red), as a 2-dimensional array.

Just out of curiosity -- you're clearly aware of the existence of the enum for specifying imread modes,  having used cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE. So, why do you revert to using a magic number with a comment explaining its meaning, instead of using cv2.IMREAD_COLOR?

Thanks, so I can extract the red values simply by using red = imgage[:,:,2]. True, the shape of the image is then two dimensional.  But why I do then see a grayscaled image when plotting the result of that: cv2.imshow('image', red)? What changes, though, is the intensitiy of the grayscaled image, such as when using values 0 or 1 instead of 2:  red = imgage[:,:,1].  So when I plot the result just to check if I selected the correct color, the image is always a grayscaled version, no matter if I choose values 0, 1, or 2.

imshow/imwrite treat any single channel array/image as grayscale. The arrays themselves don't store any information about what the actual meaning of the values they contain.

Thank you a lot, I understand. In sum, the solution to my problem is way, way easier than I thought and straightforward. I can directly select a color channel, such as red via red = imgage[:,:,2]. The result of that is a 2D numpy array. And from there on I can proceed.

@Philipp Can you close the question if the answer fits you ?
